# Strange PHP UTF-8 Behaviour

Tags: php, linux, apache, utf-8, preg-replace

I have the following test PHP code:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$text = 'Développeur Web';
var_dump($text);

$text = preg_replace('#[^\\pL\d]+#u', '-', $text);
var_dump($text);

$text = trim($text, '-');
var_dump($text);

$text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
var_dump($text);

$text = strtolower($text);
var_dump($text);

$text = preg_replace('#[^-\w]+#', '', $text);
var_dump($text);
```

On my local machine it's working as expected:

```
string(16) "Développeur Web" 
string(16) "Développeur-Web" 
string(16) "Développeur-Web" 
string(16) "D'eveloppeur-Web" 
string(16) "d'eveloppeur-web" 
string(15) "developpeur-web"
```

but on my live server it's behaving strangely:

```
string 'Développeur Web' (length=16)
string '-pp-' (length=4)
string 'pp' (length=2)
string 'pp' (length=2)
string 'pp' (length=2)
string 'pp' (length=2)
```

The local machine is Windows running PHP version 5.2.4 and the live server is CentOS running PHP version 5.2.10 so they aren't identical by any means, not ideal I know.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and can point me in the right direction? I'm assuming it's some kind of server or PHP configuration related to UTF-8 or locale.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Strange. I'm not great with Regexes - can you elaborate what that first preg_replace() thingy is doing?

Comment: I initially thought of `mb_default_encoding()` but that library has no connection to the `preg_*` functions.

Comment: The first regular expression should replace non letter or digits with "-" it's come from a Symfony tutorial http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/08

Comment: @Pekka: I think the regex is intended to replace every character not being a digit or not being a character of the Unicode property `L` (that is a `Letter`) by a `-`. See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: @Stefan cheers! That was the part I was missing. In that case, it would be worth checking whether, as the manual says, `PCRE is compiled with "--enable-unicode-properties"` (although there should be an error message if it isn't).

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I've just discovered that myself - see the comment on the other answer. Now I need to work out how to update PCRE with Unicode Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
$text = preg_replace('#[^\pL\d]+#u', '-', $text);
```

in line 6. If you escape the `\` you'll have a literal `\` in your exclusion class. So the regex `[^\\pL\d]+` finds one or more occurrences of a character not being a `\`, `p`, `L` or a digit. This would explain why `"Développeur Web"` will be reduced to `"-pp-"` - everything up to the first `p` matches and will be replaced by a `-`; the same is true for everything after the second `p`.

<del>Perhaps there is a difference between both machines in how an escaped `\` is treated.</del>

**EDIT** after OP comment:

Actually escaping the `\` is no problem here - both versions are treated the same way. What actually seems to be the problem ist, that the used PCRE version does not support unicode properties and wasn't compiled with `--enable-unicode-properties`.

Comment: I've replaced the pattern as you suggested and i'm still not getting the desired result.

Comment: I've been looking into it myself and think it may have something to do with PCRE.. still looking now.

Comment: pcretest -C
PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack

Comment: Can you verify that PCRE is built with `--enable-unicode-properties` on your live system?

Comment: **No Unicode properties support** seems to be the root of the problem. Due to the missing support, the regex `'#[^\\pL\d]+#u'` will actually be treated the way I wrote above - it doesn't recognize the special meaning of `\pL`.

Comment: The live server shows "No Unicode properties support" in a pcretest -C command so it's not. I suspect this is the problem - trying to work out how to reconfigure it now.

Comment: I've managed to recompile pcre thanks to http://gaarai.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/ and I now have "Unicode properties support" the first regular expression is now being passed correctly thanks Stefan. 

However there's now a problem with the iconv command, that's outputting D?veloppeur-Web

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I'm happy that pcre was the issue in this case and that is sorted. However the script still isn't outputting correctly but this is another issues with iconv so I've raised another question on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156983/php-iconv-glibc-to-libiconv-on-centos-5-5