# PHP ICONV glibc to libiconv on CentOS 5.5

Tags: php, centos, glibc, iconv

I'm having a few issues with the PHP function iconv, which I've tracked down the the iconv implementation. As the manual states, "Note that the iconv function on some systems may not work as you expect. In such case, it'd be a good idea to install the GNU libiconv library." https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php

I've downloaded the libiconv library from http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/ and installed it without any problems using:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
```

My problem now is how to link this installation to PHP? From what i've read I need to recompile PHP with

```
--with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/
```

but how do I do this on CentOS? I installed php with

```
yum install php.x86_64
```

I tried **yum reinstall php** but when I **service httpd restart** my phpinfo reads the same, **glibc**.

Is there a better way to install libiconv on CentOS? If not how do I get PHP using this installation without upsetting yum?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually recompile the php iconv extension (in the `php-x.y.z/ext/iconv/` subdirectory) after manual changing of the configure script to force it to select GNU libiconv instead of glibc's iconv. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743080/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-the-libiconv-version-of-iconv-instead-of-the-centos-in/4851065#4851065) for the similar Stack question.

Comment: I've just looked at your other answer and it looks spot on. I'll try to find some time this week to give it a try. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

compiled php from source seems to be the way

`php -m > /tmp/php.modules` to list of compiled module for php

backup your current php.ini

`yum uninstall php`

download the php
and base on your existing module + iconv - almost all steps has been detailed here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php#90478 (except never advise u to backup php.ini)

Comment: Thanks ajreal. I was hoping there would be an easier 'one click' method but I'll compile from source.

Comment: Peter, what options did you use when you compiled with iconv? After compiling PHP from source, it seems that glibc is still the iconv version that PHP is using.