# How can I force PHP to use the libiconv version of iconv instead of the CentOS-installed glibc version?

Tags: php, linux, apache, glibc, iconv

The code I'm working on runs perfectly on Windows XP and on Mac OS X. When testing it on CentOS (and on Fedora and Ubuntu), it's not working properly. Searching the nets led me to the conclusion that it's the `glibc` version of the `iconv` that's causing the problem. So now I need the `libiconv` version of `iconv` for Zend Lucene to work properly.

I already downloaded libiconv and configured it with `--prefix=/usr/local`, `make`, then `make install` without any errors. It seems that it was successfully installed because executing `/usr/local/bin/iconv --version` says the version is the `libiconv`. Although a simple `iconv --version` still gives the `glibc` version.

Then I recompiled PHP from source using `--with-iconv=/usr/local`. But still, the `phpinfo()` is showing the `iconv` being used is the `glibc` version. I've also already tried several other compiles using `--with-iconv-dir` or using `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Of course, I restarted the web server after recompiling PHP.

I have the following line in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

and `libphp5.so` is actually in `/usr/lib/httpd/modules`.

`phpinfo()` shows PHP 5.3.3. I also yum removed the pre-installed PHP 5.1.* just to make sure. But the iconv is still using the glibc version.

`ldd /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` gives

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x003b1000)
/usr/local/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so (0x00110000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x001ed000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x0021f000)
libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x003b2000)
libldap-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0 (0x0026e000)
liblber-2.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.3.so.0 (0x00370000)
libiconv.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2 (0x00516000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x002a8000)
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 (0x00228000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00328000)
libcurl.so.3 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3 (0x00f23000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0033b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00364000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x0037e000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00f5f000)
libssl.so.6 => /lib/libssl.so.6 (0x0862c000)
libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x04145000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x08e2d000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0611a000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x005f4000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0024e000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/libidn.so.11 (0x071f5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x08aa6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00397000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00251000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x0748a000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0x07ddf000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x062b7000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00369000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0913b000)
libsepol.so.1 => /lib/libsepol.so.1 (0x07eb4000)
```

This is a cross-post from: [NullPointer.ph](http://nullpointer.ph/questions/2922/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-the-libiconv-version-of-iconv-instead-of-the-centos-installed-glibc-version)

Comment: what does `ldd /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` and `ldd /usr/libexec/httpd/httpd` show? AFAIK, apache depends on `libiconv` as well. You can't load two version of `libiconv` in a process.

Comment: Updated question to reflect `ldd /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`. The second command gives me a `No such file or directory`.

Comment: try to configure with `--with-iconv=shared,/usr/local`

Comment: @Ismail, I tried this one as well but didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just have changed my php-5.3.3 from glibc's iconv to GNU libiconv through the manual recompiling of the php iconv extension. Follow these steps:

1. download php-5.3.3 [source code](http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.3.tar.bz2) package
2. extract it and go into `php-5.3.3/ext/iconv` subdirectory
3. execute `phpize` command (if you have no such command then install `php-devel` package)
4. (*) edit configure file (`vim configure`): add `iconv_impl_name=""` at 4664 line (exact line number on your system configuration may be different):

   ```
   ...
   iconv_impl_name=""
       if test -z "$iconv_impl_name"; then
         { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking if using GNU libiconv" >&5<
   ...
   ```
5. `./configure --with-iconv=/usr/local|grep iconv`:

   ```
   checking if using GNU libiconv... yes
   ```
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`

And now I run `php -i|grep "iconv impl"` and got:

```
iconv implementation => libiconv
```

* This trick forces configure to select the GNU libiconv instead of glibc's iconv. By default it checks for glibc's iconv at first step and does not check for GNU libiconv at all.

Comment: Makes me wonder why glibc is the default implementation being used for Linux while libiconv is the default for Mac and Windows.

Comment: Just a head's up -- not sure if it makes any difference, but the above method didn't quite work for me while trying to compile PHP 5.3.8 from source, as the main PHP ./configure didn't pick up or honor the change of the ext/iconv/configure script.  So I went ahead and made the above change to the main ./configure script at the top level php-5.3.8 directory, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Your module (`libphp5.so`) is linked to two shared libraries which are providing the same symbol (in this case the symbol is `iconv` and the libraries are `libiconv.so.2` and probably `libc.so.6`).

When this happen, the first loaded symbol is used: probably `libc.so.6` gets loaded before `libiconv.so.2` and thus it's the one providing you with the `iconv` symbol.

You can force the dynamic loader to load a library before any other; you can do this by setting the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to the library you want to preload.

I'm not an expert about Apache, so I'm not totally sure about how it works, how it starts its process and what processes it uses, but I think that setting `LD_PRELOAD` before running apache should do the trick:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2
```

---

A little example to show `LD_PRELOAD` in action:

Will compile `myfopen.c` as a shared library (`myfopen.so`): it will provide a `fopen` symbol (already defined in `libc`):

```
$ cat myfopen.c
int fopen(const char *path, const char *mode){ return -1; }
$ gcc -o libmyfopen.so myfopen.c -shared
```

Compiling `printfopen.c` as an executable (`printfopen`) which just prints the result of `fopen`; will link it against both `libc` and `libmyfopen` (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed to let the linker look for the libraries also in `.`):

```
$ cat printfopen.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {
    printf( "%d\n", fopen("","") );
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o printfopen printfopen.c -L. -lmyfopen
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd printfopen
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb779d000)
    libmyfopen.so => ./libmyfopen.so (0xb779a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb762f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb779e000)
```

Now I'm running it, to test if `LD_PRELOAD` works:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./printfopen
-1
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc.so.6 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./printfopen
0
$ LD_PRELOAD=libmyfopen.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./printfopen
-1
```

By default it loads `libmyfopen` before `libc`, then I tried to force loading `libc` and then `libmyfopen` first.

I guess that in your case `libc` is getting loaded before `libiconv` because the former is loaded by the application (apache?) before it loads the PHP module.

Comment: I ran `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2`, and restarted apache httpd but iconv is still using the glibc implementation. What am I missing?

Comment: @Randell: are you sure that the processes loading the PHP module have been started with `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable correctly set? Try and inspect PHP env vars. Maybe apache start script reset the environment prior to start apache daemon?

Comment: @Randell: try using the `export` command to export `LD_PRELOAD` to the environment: `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2`. Then if you want to check if `LD_PRELOAD` is in the environment from PHP you could use PHP [`getenv` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) or [`$_ENV` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) (not sure about the difference between the two: try using both).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) is set properly for httpd (web server) process?
If not, try setting it like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

... in the script that starts the process (i.e. `apachectl`).

The `ldd` output you showed looks correct, but you invoked `ldd` from user's environment, and httpd's might be different.

It could also help to set PATH to "/usr/local/bin:${PATH}", just in case.

Comment: I ran `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that this question is already answered and almost dead, but recently I tried to find a way to compile PHP with libiconv because in PHP I couldn't convert "∙" from UTF8 to CP1251 even with iconv //IGNORE.
But I found another solution that worked for me without recompilation (just use //TRANSLIT):

iconv("UTF8", "CP1251//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $text)

//TRANSLIT will transliterate **ONLY** unknown characters (not all, as some may guess), so it converts Russian 'ё', but transliterates unknown '∙' to  0x95 (which looks the same in the target charset).

Comment: Sadly, it ain't dead.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about CentOS, but in debian based distributions, like Ubuntu, you can choose the version of the program that you want to lauch defining the symbolic links at /etc/alternatives.

So, if you change the symbolink link /etc/alternatives/iconv in order to point to /usr/local/bin/iconv, this point forward  it should use the correct version.

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/91

Comment: `/etc/alternatives` applies to executables, not libraries.