# Why php iconv() function in server throw exception

Tags: php

I have this code.

```
$html = 'In 2007, the President’s Office and Business';
$html = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $html);
```

This work locally. But int in the server throw exception

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

How can I fix it. Maybe need to change some config??

Comment: Do local and the server have identical versions of PHP?

Comment: PHP 5.6.38 in both @ceejayoz

Comment: If you replace `TRANSLIT` with `IGNORE` then does it work? It's probably having an issue with the smart-quote `’`.

Comment: Is the actual PHP file encoded with UTF-8 on both servers? Where is the data coming from which supplies `$html`?

Comment: `In 2007, the President’s Office and Business` result when `$html = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $html);` @MonkeyZeus

Comment: The actual data come in db @MonkeyZeus

Comment: So do you have separate databases? Are they identical in collation, charset, and everything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189408/discussion-between-davit-and-monkeyzeus).

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743080/2191572 which may or may not be useful. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks your post is useful @MonkeyZeus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189408/discussion-between-davit-and-monkeyzeus) it was discovered that the library behind `iconv()` is different for localhost versus the server as seen below:

> Local: glibc 1.14 (Windows)
>
> Server: libiconv 2.19 (Linux)

To solve this discrepancy you need to either upgrade your local version or downgrade the server version.

Since the server version seems to be buggy I would recommend downgrading it so that you can have working code.

This could be of use: [How can I force PHP to use the libiconv version of iconv instead of the CentOS-installed glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743080/2191572)