# Iconv after transition from ubuntu 18.04 to centos 8

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, iconv, centos8

I changed servers, I went from ubuntu 18.04 to centos 8, I use iconv to create my links from the page title when there is a special character.

The title may be: Perchè Luigi andrà al mare.

In ubuntu 18.04 I got this link: 1-perche-luigi-andra-al-mare.html

In centos 8 I get this: 1-perch-luigi-andr-al-mare.html

What am I missing? I have searched, but everyone says that iconv is included in php, in other centos libraries, etc., etc., etc. So, should work...

But it doesn't seem to work, the special characters disappear.
What can I do to get back to the links like in Ubuntu?

Comment: Could it be that the default params for `iconv` on centos 8 are different to those on ubuntu? I.e. the default iconv params on centos 8 simply strip non ASCII characters

Comment: And how can I check or change the default parameters?

Comment: My advice is to be specific about the params you want to use on centos or run a simple test at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

Assuming you are talking about [PHP Iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php). As per [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

> **Caution**
>
> If and how //TRANSLIT works exactly depends on the system's iconv() implementation (cf. ICONV_IMPL). Some implementations are known to ignore //TRANSLIT, so the conversion is likely to fail for characters which are illegal for the out_charset.

Mentioned under **Parameters** section under `out_charset`.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743080/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-the-libiconv-version-of-iconv-instead-of-the-centos-i).